# Efficient method to find the index of the single different element between two lists in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, xor

If I have two lists each with elements that can be one of two possible values and the two lists are identical except for one value, which method should I use to find the index of that value? I am going to code this in Python as background information

Method A:

```
1. represent both lists as a binary literals  
2. use XOR on the two binary literals to give a value "v" that is a power of 2  
3. finally, use math.log(v, 2) to get the index
```

or Method B:

```
just iterate through both lists until a different element is found and 
get the index
```

or another way using Python?

Comment: So if you have `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,4]` Get the index of 3 and 4 in both lists?

Comment: Are they already represented as lists?

Comment: @Haidro yes, that is the example I am talking about

Comment: @Jared I have to decide which representation to use, I am leaning on bits because they are more space efficient and I have to find an exponential combination of values

Comment: @KevinHwang Is it guaranteed that the two list differ at same position in the list?

Comment: This question has partially been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924836/how-to-check-whether-two-lists-are-circularly-identical/26948371#26948371

Answer (score 2):

Converting your lists to another representation would involve iterating through them -- might as well iterate to find the difference itself.

Comment: This is assuming your lists are actually Python lists. If what you have is some textual representation of lists, say, then depending on what you intend to use them for it might make sense to represent them as numbers in memory, and in that case you should simply implement both approaches to finding the difference and measure which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the "best" way, but you could use python to get the difference of two sets, and then return the index:

```
xs= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] # i.e. xs(5) and ys(6) are different


xs.index( list(set(xs) - set(ys))[0] )
ys.index( list(set(ys) - set(xs))[0] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first method is better. You can modify it further.

`xor` the two list and store the result in a variable say `k`.  Find a set bit in k. Now `xor` all the elements with this bit set to `1` . You will get one number. `xor` this number with `k` to get the other.

Find the two numbers in the lists to know which list each belongs to and indices of the numbers.