# Fast way to compare cyclical data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, compare

Suppose I have the data set {A,B,C,D}, of arbitrary type, and I want to compare it to another data set. I want the comparison to be true for {A,B,C,D}, {B,C,D,A}, {C,D,A,B}, and {D,A,B,C}, but not for {A,C,B,D} or any other set that is not ordered similarly. What is a fast way to do this?

Storing them in arrays,rotating, and doing comparison that way is an O(n^2) task so that's not very good.

My first intuition would be to store the data as a set like {A,B,C,D,A,B,C} and then search for a subset, which is only O(n). Can this be done any faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether two lists are circularly identical in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924836/how-to-check-whether-two-lists-are-circularly-identical-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fast algorithm for finding the minimum rotation of a string - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation. So you can store and compare the minimum rotation.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a directed graph.  Set up a graph with the following transitions:

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
D -> A
```

All other transitions will put you in an error state.  Thus, provided each member is unique (which is implied by your use of the word *set*), you will be able to determine membership provided you end on the same graph node on which you started.

If a value can appear multiple times in your search, you'll need a smarter set of states and transitions.

This approach is useful if you precompute a single search and then match it to many data points.  It's not so useful if you have to constantly regenerate the graph.  It could also be cache-inefficient if your state table is large.

Answer (score 0):

Well Dr Zoidberg, if you are interested in order, as you are, then you need to store your data in a structure that preserves order and also allows for easy rotation.
In Python a list would do.

Find the smallest element of the list then rotate each list you want to compare until the smallest element of them is at the beginning. Note: this is not a sort, but a rotation. With all the lists for comparison so normalised, a straight forward list compare between any two would tell if they are the same after rotation.

```
>>> def rotcomp(lst1, lst2):
    while min(lst1) != lst1[0]:
        lst1 = lst1[1:] + [lst1[0]]
    while min(lst2) != lst2[0]:
        lst2 = lst2[1:] + [lst2[0]]
    return lst1 == lst2

>>> rotcomp(list('ABCD'), list('CDAB'))
True
>>> rotcomp(list('ABCD'), list('CDBA'))
False
>>> 
>>> rotcomp(list('AABC'), list('ABCA'))
False
>>> def rotcomp2(lst1, lst2):
    return repr(lst1)[1:-1] in repr(lst2 + lst2)

>>> rotcomp2(list('ABCD'), list('CDAB'))
True
>>> rotcomp2(list('ABCD'), list('CDBA'))
False
>>> rotcomp2(list('AABC'), list('ABCA'))
True
>>>
```

**NEW SECTION: WITH DUPLICATES?**

If the input may contain duplicates then, (from the possible twin question mentioned under the question), An algorithm is to see if one list is a sub-list of the other list repeated twice.

function rotcomp2 uses that algorithm and a textual comparison of the repr of the list contents.

Comment: This would fail on `AABC` and `ABCA`

Comment: There are duplicates allowed? All that talk of storing as sets wouldn't allow either duplicates or order. How colloquial is the description?