# How can I remove nested list items from a python list if they have the same order, but start at a different index

Tags: python

How to remove 'circularly-similar' lists from a nested list. Two lists are 'circularly-similar' if they are the same after some circular rotation. For example
`[1,2,3,4]` is circularly-similar to `[3,4,1,2]` because `[1,2,3,4]` rotated by 2 is `[3,4,1,2]`

Let's say I have the following list:

```py
list = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I would like to have `[0, 1, 1]` removed, because it is circularly-similar to `[1, 1, 0]` after rotation by 2. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: How is `[0, 1, 1]` the same order as `[1, 1, 0]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an element from a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman see it as a sort of modulo, if you shift the index by 1, you will have the same list.

Comment: No @Countour-Integral

Comment: @HiddevanEsch Actually, by two (or by minus one)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python and see if you can solve this yourself

Comment: @ChayimFriedman shifting can be done to both the right and left? No need to be smart here, please let me know how you would approach this problem.

Comment: Check the above mentioned question

Comment: You can shift a list `l` i to the right by doing `l[i:] + l[:i]`.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine where *duplicates* exist or which one of a pair to remove?

Comment: Ok, would you have to remove the item `[2,1,3]` if the item `[1,2,3]` preceded it?

Comment: Don't overwrite builtin `list`

Comment: @quamrana No, but yes for `[2, 3, 1]`

Comment: Do you need to preserve order?

Comment: Sublists are of arbitrary length?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26924836/7884305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to check if two lists are the same under rotation

```
# not very efficient algorithm but it works
# you can also import deque from collections for rotation operation

def is_circular_equal(a,b):
   if len(a) != len(b):
      return False  # if they are not of equal length
   for i in range(len(a)):
      if b == a[i:]+a[:i]:
         return True
   return False
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924836/how-to-check-whether-two-lists-are-circularly-identical-in-python) is another post on how to do it.

Then loop through the list of lists to check if each is is_circular_equal as the other

Comment: Could be considered out of scope, but I would at least make sure that they have the same length.

Comment: Using `collections.deque` is better, esp. if there are multiple lists with many elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2150108/7884305

Comment: @L3viathan ya, I don't wanna make the code longer. But its necessary to check that they have the same length, and return False otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bad solution (quadratic complexity):

```
def rotated_eq(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and any(a == b[i:]+b[:i] for i in range(len(a)))


def prune_rotated_dupes(ls):
    result = []
    for element in ls:
        for existing in result:
            if rotated_eq(element, existing):
                break
        else:
            result.append(element)
    return result


list_in = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

assert prune_rotated_dupes(list_in) == [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

---

For a good solution, I would think about whether you can somehow generate a unique value for each rotated-identical list, and then use that value as an element of a set to test for existence.

Comment: Would it help to make the sub-lists colection.deques?

Comment: I guess it would help with the cost of the rotation, but it wouldn't solve the issue of the nested for-loops. It's quadratic even if you assume `rotated_eq` is O(1).

Comment: It would be better if you would divide into groups by list length

Comment: The best for complexity is using tuples and sets. The conversion (list->tuple->back to list) can be more expensive, but if there are many lists this can still be better

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sure. But all this doesn't change the asymptotic complexity, which is why I consider it premature optimization. Once the main problem is solved (generating a key value for each list) this probably won't even be necessary.

Comment: itertools.product/combinations would push the complexity to C.

Comment: @L3viathan a) Asymptotic complexity isn't all in life. b) Grouping by length does change the average complexity

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In general I agree with that, but when it seems so tangible to make it linear I don't see the point in improving average complexity (yet). Same comment wrt. wwii's remark.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
xs = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]                                                                                                                                                              

sorted_list = list(map(lambda x: sorted(x), xs))

final_list = []

for x in sorted_list:

    if x in final_list:
        continue
    final_list.append(x)
```

Comment: This does not solve the above but compares unordered list (which is already covered at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7828867/7884305)